# Make an hovering background have the link it's title has

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background, hover

So I'm facing a really big problem. I have an image that when hovered, a white box with a title appears. Now the title has a link to a page but not the box. I tried many thing (eg: applying "display:inline-block;" to the css (...)) but still no link was applyed. The point is for each box to have the same link has the title it contains.

The link to the page is:

http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/portfolio/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.cosmo-thumb-view.title-over article section .padding_visible > a{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside out. Set the size to the link, and the rest will size accordingly. You can do this with very little CSS.

```css
/* Everything is an inline block to make it easy, although not strictly necessary */
.entry-content,
.padding_visible,
.padding_visible a {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* I've made this a background now. You can do this using inline styles of course, for your image gallery. */
.entry-content {
  background-image: url('http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/rsz_untitled-6707.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Let the a define the padding, that way, it covers the whole of its parents,
   and you can even click outside the white area. */
.padding_visible a {
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* Eliminate some extra space at the bottom */
}

/* Let the  span size it. It will strech the a and its parents. */
.entry-content .padding_visible a span {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Trick: change the span when the a is hovered. */
.entry-content .padding_visible a:hover span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="entry-content ">
  <div class="padding_visible">
    <a href="http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/gallery/le-quinta-vintage-my-vintage-wedding-portugal/" rel="bookmark">
      <span class="entry-title the-title-hover">
        THE QUINTA MY VINTAGE WEDDING PORTUGAL                 
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="entry-content ">
  <div class="padding_visible">
    <a href="http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/gallery/le-quinta-vintage-my-vintage-wedding-portugal/" rel="bookmark">
      <span class="entry-title the-title-hover">
        THE QUINTA MY VINTAGE WEDDING PORTUGAL                 
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="entry-content ">
  <div class="padding_visible">
    <a href="http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/gallery/le-quinta-vintage-my-vintage-wedding-portugal/" rel="bookmark">
      <span class="entry-title the-title-hover">
        THE QUINTA MY VINTAGE WEDDING PORTUGAL                 
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The comment below already worked (i started from the bottom) Really appreciate the time you spent thank you!